# How to give return url for a Standard Edit Page

Tags: custom-button

I have used a standard Edit page of Contact to open on Click of a Custom Button. The Custom Button is present on Order detail page. But I want that when the user saves the record after editing, the Url should be redirected back to the Order page.

I have used the following code right now
/{!MiC_Order__c.ContactOfCustomer__c}/e to open the edit page.

But I get the error when I am using the return URL.

/{!MiC_Order__c.ContactOfCustomer__c}/e?&retURL=/{!MiC_Order__c.Name}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a try and see if it works

```
/{!MiC_Order__c.ContactOfCustomer__c}/e?retURL=%2F{!MiC_Order__c.Id}
```